# how to get distinct values from mongodb through java with specific condition

Tags: java, mongodb

i am trying to get distinct values from mongodb with java
in particular unique id but i dont found this .

```
DB database = MongoConnection.getInstance();
            DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("licence_entery_fl3_fl1");
            BasicDBObject wheremap = new BasicDBObject();
            wheremap.put("int_distillery_id", act.getDist_id());
            wheremap.put("vch_licence_type", act.getVch_to());     
            wheremap.put("vch_lic_unit_type", "D");
            DBCursor cursor = collection.find(wheremap);  
            Iterator<DBObject> itr   =   cursor.iterator();
     log.info("Fetching all documents from the collection licence_entery_fl3_fl1  ---------"+itr);
     
     while(itr.hasNext()){
         DBObject record = itr.next();
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
            Mongo_GatepassToWholesale_20_21_Model model = mapper.readValue(record.toString(), Mongo_GatepassToWholesale_20_21_Model.class);
         
            System.out.println("--licence_nmbr.--"+model.licence_nmbr+"---");
            item.setValue(model.vch_licence_no);
            item.setLabel(model.licence_nmbr);
            
            list.add(item);
            
     }
```

this is implement for jsf .
please help me

Comment: There's a "distinct" function in mongo which takes conditions and key for which you need distinct values after filteration, see if that helps.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use spring data as an ORM with a specific datasource, so you can go through criteria like the following using regex :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").regex("^A"));
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query,User.class);
```

or to have a select by identifier only used the **MongoRepository** interface by a findDistinctById() as ou can see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) -- see chapter 6.3. Query methods --